# RSRuby installation and R configuration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r

I tried to install RSRuby following the steps mentioned in http://web.kuicr.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~alexg/rsruby/manual.pdf  and http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/baby-steps-with-rsruby-in-rails/ and I must say that nsaunders blog is indeed a great start for anyone installing RSRuby. But when I tried to check from the irb by creating an instance of RSRuby:

```
r = RSRuby.instance
```

it returned me error:

```
   1.8.7-p371 :001 > r = RSRuby.instance
   NameError: uninitialized constant RSRuby
from (irb):1
```

I have all the prerequisites: R_HOME, shared lib option and other stuff. I dont know why I got this error. Any ideas guyzz?????

has anyone tried it for rails successfully???

Comment: Did you "require rubygems" and "require rsruby" first? However, RSRuby is old and not updated in some time. I've moved to Ruby 1.9 and can't get it to compile with that. I'd suggest that you install Rserve and try the rserve-client gem instead.

Comment: Even I think shifting to rserve-client gem is a good option. I am restricted to use Ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.11 because of the project requirements. So I am a bit hesitand in choosing my options. Anyways I will try Rserve and then lets see..!

Comment: Sorry I didnt try require 'rubygems'. When I did with require 'rsruby', it worked. Thanx neilfws.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full source code it's difficult to give you an answer, so this is just a guess. Did you remember to require 'rsruby' within your code? NameError is often caused when a gem is installed but the code does not include the appropriate require statement:

```
require 'rsruby'
r = RSRuby.instance
```

You can see this in the code example in the "Documentation" section of the README in the [GitHub project](https://github.com/alexgutteridge/rsruby).

Comment: Well yeah I tried this single line of code on irb. There I did not mentioned any require 'rsruby'. But yeah in the rails app, when I was trying an example, http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/baby-steps-with-rsruby-in-rails/, I did mention it, but I did not get the expected output and this forced me to simply check on irb if its detecting the rsruby gem.

Comment: Thanx jerry for the reply actully we need to include require 'rubygems' also with the above code to make it work, as mentioned above by neilfws. Thanx for the reply.